# To remove last comma from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Here, I am using multiple data in mysql insert query. I am using comma `","` in last. But If I want to remove last comma from insert query, how can we do that?
My query is:

```
 $sql.= INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method,order_id,box_id,rate,signature,weight,length,width,height,value,markupPercentage,insured) VALUES("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","99999","0","0","21.9","24","24","21","200","","0"),("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","88888","0","0","18","20","20","18","140","","0"),("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","88888","0","0","18","20","20","18","140","","0"),;
```

**Updated:**
I want like this,

```
$sql.= INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method,order_id,box_id,rate,signature,weight,length,width,height,value,markupPercentage,insured) VALUES("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","99999","0","0","21.9","24","24","21","200","","0"),("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","88888","0","0","18","20","20","18","140","","0"),("Pickup - Deliver By Messenger: Approximately 1 Business Day, by 5 PM","15566","88888","0","0","18","20","20","18","140","","0");
```

Comment: Press the Backspace key? (I'm pretty sure that's not the answer you were looking for, but your question is too vague for anything better).

Comment: i believe you are trying to solve the wrong problem. How was the comma put there in the first place?

Comment: It is in loop so I am getting good result but also getting last comma in query.

Comment: @ringo: It is PHP..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are creating your sql string in a loop:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES "

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $sql .= "('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),"
}
```

then you can just remove the last comma with rtim:

```
rtrim($sql, ",")
```

but I would suggest you to use a prepared statement with placeholders instead. If you are using mysqli it's something like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $value1, $value2, $value3);

for (....) {
  $value1 = 'something';
  $value2 = 'something';
  $value3 = 'something';

  $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks @fthiella: Should I have use $sql = rtrim($sql,",") OR use direct rtrim($sql,",")..?

Comment: @ViralBhoot you can use `$sql =  rtrim($sql,",")` or if you have `,;` you can use for example `$sql = rtrim($sql, ",;") . ";";` but I would suggest you to use a prepared statement if possible

Comment: Thanks but rtrim removes all the comma after multiple values in insert queries and as I want to remove last comma.

Comment: @ViralBhoot you have to use rtrim after the loop and not inside the loop, if you use it after the loop it will remove only the last comma